# serve json file to user in django

Tags: json, django

How do you serve a JSON file to user?
Currently I have a JSON object that I want the user to download.

I tried:

```
res = HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
res['Content_disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=result.json'
```

but it still serves the json in the browser instead of making user download it.

Comment: Did the below answer solved your case?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment):

```
response = HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="result.json"'
```

Comment: It's the same as what I tried, but it serves the json in the browser instead of having a download popup.